# Sendmessage proclaims that "there is no reciever" Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sendmessage

I created two game objects, one which was named textBox, and another named Toutch. Each of these game objects than recieved their own c# script. The textBox object was assigned: NPCtext.cs and the other object, Toutch, was assigned ToutchPepper.cs:

ToutchPepper cs file:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ToutchPepper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject self;
    private bool onObject=false;
    public GameObject textBox;

    void Start()
    {
        self.SetActive(true);
    }
    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        onObject = true;
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        onObject = false;
    }
    void Update(){
        Debug.Log(onObject+"pepper");
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(onObject){
                textBox.GetComponent<NPCtext>().SendMessage("chiliPepper");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NPCtext.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NPCtext : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private TextMeshProUGUI DIALOUGE;
    [SerializeField]public TextMeshProUGUI Name;
    [SerializeField]private Sprite[] NPCS;
    [SerializeField]public Image NPC_IMAGE;
    public static string pause="True";
    [SerializeField]public GameObject main;
    private int DioOn=0;
    private string[] names={"eylmo","poopoohead","redPepper","yellowPepper"};
    private string[] startDio={"hello","there"};
    void Start()
    {
        sayText();
    }
    public void setText(string x, int y)
    {
        main.SetActive(true);
        DIALOUGE.text=x;
        NPC_IMAGE.sprite=NPCS[y];
        Name.text=names[y];
    }

    void sayText()
    {
        setText(startDio[DioOn],0);
    }

    public void Next(){
        //Debug.Log(DioOn<startDio.Length);
        if(DioOn<startDio.Length-1){
            pause="True";
            DioOn+=1;
            sayText();
        }else{
            pause="False";
            main.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void chiliPepper(){
        Debug.Log("oki");
    }
}
```

Now, as you can see I am trying to use SendMessage, asking to use the chiliPepper void, but it just gives me an error:

SendMessage chiliPepper has no receiver!
UnityEngine.Component:SendMessage (string)

Comment: No need for SendMessage, you already have your script connection with GetComponent. Remove it from the line and it will work.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html
Look here there is a stub "Messages", feg. "Start", "Awake", "Update" etc. You can use SendMessage to invoke these functions on every script attached to a game object. In your case you probobaly just want to invoke method like that "textBox.GetComponent<NPCtext>().chiliPepper()"